# VBA Visio - locate multiple tet-based shapes with the same fill color

Tags: vba, visio

As per the discussion in the question here:
[VBA Visio - locate text-based shapes with the same fill color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76424249/vba-visio-locate-text-based-shapes-with-the-same-fill-color)

I would like to do this exercise in a bunch.

Therefore I've modified the code slightly, which now looks like this:

```
Sub finalsort4()
Dim vShp As Visio.Shape
Dim isText As Boolean
Dim colorColl As Collection
Dim shpColor As String, shpColor2 As String, shpColor3 As String, shpColor4 As String, 
shpColor5 As String
Dim shpColor6 As String, shpColor7 As String, shpColor8 As String, shpColor9 As String, 
shpColor10 As String
Dim filterColor As String, filterColor2 As String, filterColor3 As String, filterColor4 As 
String, filterColor5 As String
Dim filterColor6 As String, filterColor7 As String, filterColor8 As String, filterColor9 As 
String, filterColor10 As String

Set colorColl = New Collection

'Sort all shapes by fill color and locate "master" shape
For Each vShp In ActiveDocument.Pages("SLD").Shapes
    'Reset Flags
    isText = False
    shpColor = ""
    shpColor2 = ""
    shpColor3 = ""
    shpColor4 = ""
    shpColor5 = ""
    shpColor6 = ""
    shpColor7 = ""
    shpColor8 = ""
    shpColor9 = ""
    shpColor10 = ""
        
    'Extract Shape color and text from subshape
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor, isText, "*AA**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor2, isText, "*AE**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor3, isText, "*AK**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor4, isText, "*AR**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor5, isText, "*AU**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor6, isText, "*AY**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor7, isText, "*BC**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor8, isText, "*BH**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor9, isText, "*BM**")
    Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor10, isText, "*BS**")
    
    'Group shapes in collections by foreground color formula
    If Not hasKey(colorColl, shpColor) Then colorColl.Add New Collection, shpColor
    colorColl(shpColor).Add vShp
    
    'Set filter color if our shape fulfills the text filter criteria
    If isText Then filterColor = shpColor
    If isText Then filterColor2 = shpColor2
    If isText Then filterColor3 = shpColor3
    If isText Then filterColor4 = shpColor4
    If isText Then filterColor5 = shpColor5
    If isText Then filterColor6 = shpColor6
    If isText Then filterColor7 = shpColor7
    If isText Then filterColor8 = shpColor8
    If isText Then filterColor9 = shpColor9
    If isText Then filterColor10 = shpColor10
  Next vShp

  'Place shapes of desired color at specified location
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 32

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor2)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 29

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor3)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 26

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor4)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 23

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor5)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 20

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor6)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 17

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor7)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 14

  Next
  For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColor8)
    vShp.Cells("PinY") = 11

  Next

End Sub
```

Just part of them moves to the correct position. Is there a way to elaborate this code more nicely?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer below I've tweaked the code, which looks like this:

```
Sub finalsort6()

Dim filterColors As Collection, colorColl As Collection
Dim textFilter As Collection, textFilters As Collection, isText As 
String
Dim vShp As Visio.Shape

Const Y_OFFSET = 11                'Initial offset for YPin (mm)
Const Y_SPACING = 3                'Spacing between YPin placements (mm)
Set filterColors = New Collection  'Holds the filter shape colors
Set colorColl = New Collection     'Groups shapes by color

 'Create array of text filters to look for (rearrange as necessary for positioning)
 textFilters = Split("AA;AE;AK;AR;AU;AY;BC;BH;BM;BS", ";")

 'Sort all shapes by fill color and locate "master" shape
 For Each vShp In ActiveDocument.Pages("SLD").Shapes
    'Reset Flags
    isText = False
    
    'Extract Shape color and text from subshape, testing for each filter criteria
    For Each textFilter In textFilters
        'Create dynamic pattern to match
        Call GetInfo(vShp, shpColor, isText, "*" & textFilter & "**")

        'Add filter color to list
        If isText Then
            filterColors.Add shpColor, textFilter
            Exit For   'Match found: Exit textFilter loop
        End If
    Next

    'Group shapes in collections by foreground color formula
    If Not hasKey(colorColl, shpColor) Then colorColl.Add New Collection, shpColor
    colorColl(shpColor).Add vShp
  Next vShp


  'Loop over filter shape colors
  For i = 1 To filterColors.Count
    'Place shapes of desired color at specified location
    For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColors(i))
        vShp.Cells("PinY") = Y_OFFSET + (i - 1) * Y_SPACING
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

It doesn't work, unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

Argument not optional
at the line:

```
  textFilters = Split("AA;AE;AK;AR;AU;AY;BC;BH;BM;BS", ";")
```

I feel that I am pretty close to the solution, although I don't know what should be applied here.

Comment: I'm not going to fully answer your question, but I'll give you a hint: the issue lies in the `Group shapes in collections by foreground color formula` section. Or rather, in how that section is interacting with the way you've set up the rest of the code.

Comment: I don't know how to do it unfortunately.

Comment: @Vince could you share more ideas? I really don't know how to sort this out.

Comment: Each shape only has 1 fill color, so using 10 different variables to store them is pointless. For each shape, `shpColor = shpColor2 ... = shpColor10`, meaning that `filterColor = filterColor2... = filterColor10` as well. The thing that does change depending on the name is the filter `isText`, so if you're going to stick with this sort of hard-coded approach, you'll want 10 of those instead.

Comment: Yes, I understand it, but I don't know what would be the shortcut bounding them together in one or two lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my comment on the OP, I've decided to provide an answer anyways. I don't currently have access to Visio and therefore can't test this. I'll leave troubleshooting as an exercise for the OP. A better implementation would be to rewrite `getInfo()` or to format the Shapes to provide easy access to the filter/grouping criteria, but those aren't part of this question.

*This assumes that each "filter shape" only occurs once.*

```
Sub finalsort4()
    Const Y_OFFSET = 11                'Initial offset for YPin (mm)
    Const Y_SPACING = 3                'Spacing between YPin placements (mm)
    Set filterColors = New Collection  'Holds the filter shape colors
    Set colorColl = New Collection     'Groups shapes by color
    
    'Create array of text filters to look for (rearrange as necessary for positioning)
    textFilters = Split("AA;AE;AK;AR;AU;AY;BC;BH;BM;BS", ";")

    'Sort all shapes by fill color and locate "master" shape
    For Each vShp In ActiveDocument.Pages("SLD").Shapes
        'Reset Flags
        isText = False 
        
        'Extract Shape color and text from subshape, testing for each filter criteria
        For each textFilter in textFilters 
            'Create dynamic pattern to match
            Call getInfo(vShp, shpColor, isText, "*" & textFilter & "**") 

            'Add filter color to list 
            If isText then 
                filterColors.Add shpColor, textFilter
                Exit For   'Match found: Exit textFilter loop
            End IF 
        Next 

        'Group shapes in collections by foreground color formula
        If Not hasKey(colorColl, shpColor) Then colorColl.Add New Collection, shpColor
        colorColl(shpColor).Add vShp    
    Next vShp


    'Loop over filter shape colors
    For i = 1 to filterColors.Count   
        'Place shapes of desired color at specified location                                     
        For Each vShp In colorColl(filterColors(i))                        
            vShp.Cells("PinY") = Y_OFFSET + (i-1) * Y_SPACING              
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Object required for filterColors, how could I "Dim" them?

Comment: I've updated my query and pointed out where the error is.

Comment: Looking at the updated code you posted, your issues seem to be in your variable declarations. `isText` is a `Boolean` per the argument type of `GetInfo`, you've declared it as a string. The [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function returns an `Array`, but you're assigning it to a `Collection` (which would need to be assigned using `Set` anyways).

Comment: Dim filterColors As Collection, colorColl As Collection
    Dim textFilter As Object, textFilters As Object, isText As Boolean
    Dim shpColor As String, filterColor As String
    Dim vShp As Visio.Shape
    Dim i As Long

Set textFilters = Split("AA;AE;AK;AR;AU;AY;BC;BH;BM;BS", ";")  - object required error.

Where the problem might be now?

Comment: Please read about [Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function). They have an example of how the variable declaration and assignment should work.

Comment: Yes, the variable examples must be declared as String. The problem now is, that for the line of: 
For Each textFilter In textFilters
I have an error:
For Each may only iterate over a collection object or an array

Comment: `Dim textFilter as Variant` and `Dim textFilters as Variant`. You should really be able to debug _some_ of this stuff by yourself...

Comment: I do the debug and see the errors. After applying your suggestions now I am getting another error at the line:
filterColors.Add shpColor, textFilter
This key is already associated with an element of this collection.
What could I do with it?

Comment: The Collection key is assigned by `textFilter`, which looks at the last 2 letters of the label subshape. There should never be any overlap there because those labels are apparently unique. You could try adding a `Debug.Print "Filter Shape: " & vShp.Name` and `Debug.Print "Filter Text: " & textFilter` before the erroring line to try and get some information about what's happening...it could be that `textFilter` is being improperly assigned or that your data aren't as unique as you thought.

Comment: My data might not be unique when considering just two last letters. Is there any way to make this code work for nonunique values?

Comment: Sure, just ignore anything past the first one. That's what the `hasKey()` function is there to check. Add it if it doesn't have the key and ignore it otherwise. If those shapes might not be the same color I fail to see what the point of filtering is at all.

Comment: I've removed a part of them, next added up others and it's working! Thanks a lot for your invaluable help!